# Extracting Source Files from my Android App On My Phone

Tags: android

Last year I developed an Android app for my phone and loaded it on, and have been using it ever since. Unfortunately I had to reformat my computer and lost the source files to this android app. If the app was loaded in debugging mode, is there any possible way to extract the app and its source files for editing back onto my computer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use another app such as Astro to get the APK (or even a file explorer), then [decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file?rq=1)

Comment: Here is good answer 

[extracting source files from apk][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. get [APKTool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) , place its executables in a folder
2. Run `adb pull /data/app/<your_app_name>.apk` ,  now you got the apk file ,place it in same folder as apktool
3. run `./apktool d <apk_file_name> <output_folder>`, apk sources will be reconstructed in output folder.